# Swift Combine: Run publisher one after another with timeout

Tags: swift, combine

I want to run the second publisher with a timeout after the first one is published.

Something like this:

```
publisher1.flatMap{ _ in
  publisher2.timeout(1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
}
.handleEvents(receiveCancel: {

})
.sink { _ in

} receiveValue: { success in

}
```

(Note: publisher2 is a publisher which is published when a socket event is received which is not guaranteed to run all the time, so I wanted to set a timeout there so that the above can be finished even with an error.)

How can I do this?

Comment: What are your expectations if the timeout's limit is reached and publisher2 has not emitted a value?  What signal passes through the whole pipeline in that case?

Comment: @ScottThompson I want to cancel above pipeline and show some kind of error in the app if times out.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the source for a Playground that demonstrates what I think you are trying to achieve, and has some code to exercise the functionality.

In the code `publisher1` and `publisher2` are `PassthroughSubjects`, a simple publisher that's handy for using in examples because you can send values through them at any point.

In `subscribeToPipelines` the code builds a new pipeline, `withTimeout`, that takes its input from `pipeline2` and times out if nothing is published in the span of 1 second.  This is the pipeline that will take control when `pipeline1` receives a value by virtue of the `flatMap`

The result of `withTimeout` is captured by the `sink` operator.  The code handles the possible conditions of `withTimeout` it may have completed normally, it may have timeout out, and it may receive a value.  `print` statements cover all the cases.

The code exercises the pipelines using a `Task` simply because `Task.sleep` is an easy way to put in some delays.  The first exercise shows what happens if `publisher1` receives a value and `publisher2` receives a value after a half of a second.  The second exercise shows what happens if `publisher2` delays posting a value for 1 and a half seconds (it times out).

```
import UIKit
import Combine

enum MyErrors: Error {
    case publisher2Timedout
}

let publisher1 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()
let publisher2 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()

func subscribeToPipelines() -> AnyCancellable {
    let withTimeout = publisher2.timeout(1,
                                         scheduler: RunLoop.main,
                                         customError: { return MyErrors.publisher2Timedout })

    let subscription = publisher1.flatMap { value1 in
        print("The first publisher's result was \(value1)")
        return withTimeout
    }
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("The entire pipeline finished")
                case .failure(let error):
                    if case MyErrors.publisher2Timedout = error {
                        print("The second operation timed out")
                    }
            }
        } receiveValue: { value2 in
            print("The second publisher's result is \(value2)")
        }

    return subscription
}

Task {
    var subscription: AnyCancellable? =  subscribeToPipelines()
    // Try a case where the operations succeed
    publisher1.send(3)
    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(500))
    publisher2.send(4)

    subscription = nil;

    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(500))

    subscription =  subscribeToPipelines()
    publisher1.send(5)
    try  await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1500))
    publisher2.send(6)

    subscription = nil;
}
```